# Не получается добавить больше двух объектов в json-массив

Tags: python, json

Я хочу сохранить три словаря *поочередно* в json-файл в виде массива объектов.

```
import json

milk = {'Продукт': 'Молоко',
        'Калории': 100,
        }
bread = {'Продукт': 'Хлеб',
        'Калории': 200,
        }
fish = {'Продукт': 'Рыба',
        'Калории': 300,
        }

def add_food_to_database(food):
    path = '/home/dzmitry/foods.json'
    with open(path, 'r+') as jsonfile:
        if not jsonfile.read():
            data = []
            data.append(food)
            json.dump(data, jsonfile)
        else:
            jsonfile.seek(0)
            data = json.load(jsonfile)
            data.append(food)
            json.dump(data, jsonfile)
    print("Добавили продукт: ", food['Продукт'])

foods = (milk, bread, fish)
[add_food_to_database(food) for food in foods]
```

Однако добавляется почему-то только два продукта.

```
=========== RESTART: /home/dzmitry/forstack.py ===========
Добавили продукт:  Молоко
Добавили продукт:  Хлеб
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dzmitry/forstack.py", line 28, in 
    [add_food_to_database(food) for food in foods]
  File "/home/dzmitry/forstack.py", line 28, in 
    [add_food_to_database(food) for food in foods]
  File "/home/dzmitry/forstack.py", line 22, in add_food_to_database
    data = json.load(jsonfile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 268, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/decoder.py", line 342, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 140 (char 139)
>>>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: добавьте в вопрос содержимое файла "foods.json" после ошибки

Comment: протестировал ваш код, вот что выходит в JSON файле `[{"Product": "Mikl", "Calories": 100}][{"Product": "Milk", "Calories": 100}, {"Product": "Bread", "Calories": 200}]`, то есть он все добавляет, но формат JSON´а у вас получается не правильный. Выводится должно в файле как - `[{"Product": "Milk", "Calories": 100}, {"Product": "Milk", "Calories": 100}, {"Product": "Bread", "Calories": 200}]`

Comment: как показал @Insider, у Вас код `json.dump(data, jsonfile)` дописывает файл - в дополнение к предыдущим данным. Файл надо переоткрывать для создания или, по крайней мере, отматывать на начало.

Comment: Да и в итоге, в print, у вас показывает только Молоко и Хлеб, потому-что, они в правильно JSON формате.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json.load()` читает из файла, поэтому когда вы вызываете `json.dump()`, то он пишет в конец -- в итоге некорректное содержимое получается. Например, если файл содержал `[1]` список, а `food = 2`, то после `json.dump()` содержимое стало бы `[1][1,2]`, что не является JSON списком.

Минимальное изменение: добавить `jsonfile.seek(0)` перед `json.dump()` (записываемое содержимое больше, поэтому не обязательно `jsonfile.truncate(0)` или похожее вызывать, чтобы убрать предыдущее содержимое).

Можно вместо JSON-списка сохранять в файл отдельные объекты—по одному на строчку. Тогда, можно упростить `add_food_to_database()` функцию:

```
import json

def add_food_to_database(food, path='foods.json'):
    with open(path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        print(json.dumps(food, separators=(',', ':')), file=file)
```

`json.dumps()` не содержит новую строку (неэкранированный `\n` запрещён в JSON-строках и `json.dumps()` не использует `'\n'` для форматирования по умолчанию—`separators` передан явно в примере, чтобы не зависеть от значения по умолчанию).

Чтобы прочитать назад:

```
foods = [json.loads(line) for line in input_json_file]
```

Или (если вы хотите с файлом как с базой данных работать) можно использовать sqlite для сохранения записей:

```
import sqlite3 

def add_food_to_database(food, path='foods.db'):
    with sqlite3.connect(path) as db:
        db.execute('insert into food values (:product, :calories)', food)
```

Пример предполагает, что `food = {'product': 'Молоко', 'calories': 100}` или похожее и `foods.db` содежит таблицу, созданную с помощью:

```
db.execute('create table food (product, calories)')
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает! И с sqlite намного более естественно получается!